# Creating row using php loop

Tags: php

I want to create a row if columns greater than 3 using PHP loop because i am using wordpress

My code is here

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">column1</div>
    <div class="column">column2</div>
    <div class="column">column3</div>
</div>
```

If columns are greater than 3, then it should create a new row like this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">column1</div>
    <div class="column">column2</div>
    <div class="column">column3</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="column">column1</div>
  </div>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean Columns right...? or am I completely wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure - just use modulus:

```
<?php
    $elements = array('foo', 'bar', 'rab', 'oof');

    echo '<div class="row">';
    foreach ($elements as $i => $element) {
        if ($i > 0 && $i % 3 == 0) {
            echo '</div><div class="row">';
        }
        echo '<div class="column">' . $element . '</div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/o92936aw)

Output:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">foo</div>
    <div class="column">bar</div>
    <div class="column">rab</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">oof</div>
</div>
```

Comment: if i have unlimited post?

Comment: @Sajal Then this works as well? There's no count anywhere that would indicate otherwise?

Comment: $elements = array('foo', 'bar', 'rab', 'oof');  what to write on the place of foo, bar ect, sorry but i am new in php

Comment: @Sajal Your own array? Where would you get `coloum1`, `coloum2`, `coloum3`.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
<?
echo '<div class="row">';
for ($i=0; $i<15;$i++){
    if ($i%3 == 0 && $i != 0){
        echo '</div><div class="row">';
    }
    echo '<div class="column">column '.($i+1).'</div>';

}
echo '</div>';
?>
```

**[WORKING CODE](http://codepad.org/m9dm5dXL)**

Comment: I don't think, that is what the OP meant.

Comment: Your double quote is invalid.
Change the `"row"` to `'row'`
Example, `echo "</div>\n<div class='row'>";`

Comment: i i dont want to fix lenth of coloum  $i<15 if i dont want to give 15?

Comment: @Sajal this is only example. I don't know how many items do You have. If You have array for that - just use foreach loop with some counter.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but i am new in php, if you can give me an example how to set counter

Comment: Very small exaple 
$couner = 1 ; foreach ($arr as $item){ echo 'item '.$couner; $counter++; }

Comment: @Sajal You can approve answear :)

Answer (score 0):

There is alternative solution with function.

```
<?php
// Managing the Code -- Functions: Handling a Variable Number of Parameters
// building a row of 10 <td> columns with a variable number of items
function preferencesRow()
{
    // initialize $output
    $output = '';
    // use "func_get_args()" to collect all parameters into an array
    $params = func_get_args();
    // used to make sure 10 columns are filled
    $maxCols = 10;

    // loop through the parameters
    foreach ($params as $item) {
        $output .= "<td width='80px' align='center'>$item</td>\n";
        $maxCols--;
    }

    // fill in the rest of the row with empty columns
    for ($x = 0; $x < $maxCols; $x++) {
        $output .= "<td width='80px'>&nbsp;</td>\n";
    }
    return $output;
}

// NOTE: you can use "." or "," with echo
echo '<h1>Preferences</h1><hr />' . PHP_EOL;    
echo '<table border=1>' . PHP_EOL;
echo '<tr><th>Tarzan</th>';
echo preferencesRow('Africa', 'jungles', 'tantor', 'mangani', 'cabin in the woods', 
                    'hunting', 'swinging in trees', 'Jane');
echo '</tr>';
echo '<tr><th>Jane</th>';
echo preferencesRow('London', 'parties', 'dancing', 'social events', 'lavish estates');
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>' . PHP_EOL;
```